# How to determine the lane of a call activity?

Tags: java, business-process-management, bpmn, camunda

I have a Call Activity, which is used in different lanes of my BPMN diagram. There is a task inside the Call Activity. Is it possible to determine the Lane of the Call Activity from the Task?

It looks something like this in the pictures here:

[image: Process Diagram]

[image: Call Activity]

I want to determine "MyLane1" respectively "MyLane2" from inside the Task "Get parent Lane".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the BPMN Model API to determine the lane which references an activity:

```
ProcessDefinition procDef  = repositoryService.createProcessDefinitionQuery().processDefinitionKey("idOfProcess").singleResult();
BpmnModelInstance bpmnModelInstance = repositoryService.getBpmnModelInstance(procDef.getId());

CallActivity callActivity = null;

Collection<Lane> lanes = bpmnModelInstance.getModelElementsByType(Lane.class);
// iterate the lanes
for (Lane lane : lanes) {
  // iterate the flownodes referenced by the lane:
  for (FlowNode flowNode : lane.getFlowNodeRefs()) {
    if("idOfCallactivity".equals(flowNode.getId())) {
      callActivity = (CallActivity) flowNode;
      break;
    }
  }
}


if(callActivity != null) {
  // work with callactivity
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Looks like I could try something like this. I'll give it a try tomorrow and let you know how it worked out.

Comment: Ok I played with your code but there is the problem that I cannot find the ID of the Call Activity from inside the Service Task "Get parent lane". The parent of the "execution" variable in my class, which implements the JavaDelegate Interface is null.

Answer (score 1):

Using internal API you could also do

```
public void execute(DelegateExecution e) {

  ((ExecutionEntity)e).getProcessInstance()
    .getSuperExecution()
    .getActivityId()
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I needed in addition to your previous answer. You made my day :)